# How to get Requests to go to a certain webage after AUTH in

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get a table that in on an HTML page.i am using Selenium to go to the page and log in because the page i need to access is only available after you log into the site. I wanted to get a date from the site using a MAC id for a product. This date is in a table. Instead of using Selenium though i want to try and use requests as it is faster, but my problem is to access this webpage i need to log in and after i log in it takes me to the homepage which is not the page i want. How can i go to the page i want while stil saying logged in?

```py
with requests.Session() as t:
    t.get("https://www.axis.com/partner_pages/serialno.php?serialno=00-40-8C-EB-4F-AD&submit=Search", auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', "pass"))
    t.get(("https://www.axis.com/partner_pages/serialno.php?serialno"))
    print(t.)
```

Comment: Selenium and requests don't talk to each other.  Logging in with Selenium has no effect on the requests code.  If you want to do it with requests, you'll need to create a requests session and log in with that session.

Comment: @JohnGordon how can i do that? after i do the AUTH can i then .get another page?